# Excel a function as SUMIFS criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a series of dates and values:

```
8.12.2018  12
5.2.2019   32 
15.7.2019  89
```

I would like to use something like `(SUMIFS(YEAR(A1:A3);2018)` but it's not allowed.

I know, I could extract the year in a separate column, but here I want to ask, if it's possible inside the `sumifs` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I thought you couldnt, it has proven by @forwardEd, you can alter criteria in such a way to use SUMIFS, however, you could also look into `SUMPRODUCT` for this exercize:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(YEAR(A1:A3)=2018),B1:B3)
```

[image]

Comment: I prefer the `sumproduct` array calculation option as it is tidier looking and usually not that big of an issue for small sheets.  Only real deterrent I am aware of with it is one should not use full column references or you risk bogging down your system depending on how many `sumproducts` get used

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dates are valid excel dates and not dates as strings/text then you can use the SUMIFS formula for a year as follows:

```
=SUMIFS(B1:B3,A1:A3,">="&date(2018,01,01),A1:A3,"<="&date(2018,12,31))
```

Basically the formula is saying sum all the values in B1:B3 where the date in A1:A3 is greater than or equal to the first day of the year AND less than or equal to the last day of the year.  I choose to write the date using the date function as it is easier to recognize than the integer format of the date.  If you want to write just the year as a criteria in say cell c2 then replace 2018 in the above formula with c2.

UPDATE

I have not tested it but since the default for a date without time is  00:00:00 it would mean the formula above would cut off December 31 with almost any sort of time associated with it.  Therefor the better cut off would be less than January 1st of the following year instead of less than or equal to December 31st.  As such you could revise the above formula to:

```
=SUMIFS(B1:B3,A1:A3,">="&date(2018,01,01),A1:A3,"<"&date(2019,01,01))

or

Where C2 is the year as an integer
=SUMIFS(B1:B3,A1:A3,">="&date(C2,01,01),A1:A3,"<"&date(C2+1,01,01))
```

Comment: I didn't think about that! Great @ForwardEd

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach (a little bit less elegant solution, but might be more clear to less advanced users):

```
=SUMIFS(B1:B4,A1:A4,">="&"01/01/2018",A1:A4,"<="&"31/12/2018")
```

[image]

Comment: FYI writing the date in that format may not work on all system.  Ie my system does not recognize it but it does recognize 2018/12/31.

Comment: Correct - I assumed the user will know their own data format :) cheers